# How to switch between tabs using href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a tabbed pane here - [LINK](http://codepen.io/Saturnian/pen/iILfx)

In Tab 1, I have a piece of text. When clicked, I'd like it to show the second tab. I've tried all variations of  `#tab2`, `#mtabs#tab2` , etc but nothing seems to work.

How do I navigate it to the second tab's content?

HTML Code:

```
<div id="mtabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1" rel="tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" rel="tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" rel="tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab4" rel="tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="mtabs_content_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="mtab_content">
      <p><a href="#mtabs_wrapper#mtabs_content_container#tab2">Take me to Tab 2</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="mtab_content">
        <p>Tab content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="mtab_content">
        <p>Tab content 3</p>
    </div>
<div id="tab4" class="mtab_content" style="display: block;">
  <p>Tab content 4</p>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- Original tabs END -->
```

CSS Code:

```
#mtabs_wrapper {
    width: 422px;
}
#mtabs_container {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#mtabs {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0 4px 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0px;
    /* font: 0.75em arial; */
}
#mtabs li {
    display: inline;
}
#mtabs li a {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
    font-family: Artifika, serif; 
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    font-size:14px;
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: none;*/
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
#mtabs li a:hover {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    padding: 4px 6px;
}
#mtabs li.active a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 6px 5px 6px;
    /*border-bottom: none;*/
}
#mtabs li.active a:hover {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 4px 6px 5px 6px;
    /*border-bottom: none;*/
}

#mtabs li a.icon_accept {
    background-image: url(accept.png);
    background-position: 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 24px;
}
#mtabs li a.icon_accept:hover {
    padding-left: 24px;
}

#mtabs_content_container {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 600px;
}
.mtab_content {
    display: none;
}

/* TAB CSS END */
```

Javascript (jQuery actually):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //  When user clicks on tab, this code will be executed
    $("#mtabs li").click(function() {
        //  First remove class "active" from currently active tab
        $("#mtabs li").removeClass('active');

        //  Now add class "active" to the selected/clicked tab
        $(this).addClass("active");

        //  Hide all tab content
        $(".mtab_content").hide();

        //  Here we get the href value of the selected tab
        var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

        //  Show the selected tab content
        $(selected_tab).fadeIn();

        //  At the end, we add return false so that the click on the link is not executed
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post all your code here (I don't want to open a third party site with millions of trackers), but keep the link as live demo.

Comment: You will need to use JS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if You do not want to use external libraries you can use this.
Add an identifier to the link and add the click event and emulate a click on the preferred tab.
is not practical to do this.
but it is an option only if you don't want to use libraries

```
<a id="simulate">Take me to Tab 2</a>
```

look at this example.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hEpGK

Comment: Thanks a million. This worked like a charm! Could you explain the `$('a[rel="tab2"]').trigger("click");` bit?

Comment: is a selector css :

a -> tag 
[ ] -> indicates that you refer to an attribute 
rel -> atribute name
tab2 -> value

Comment: Your code works perfectly well in codepen (when I incorporated the same changes). However, when I make the same changes in my project, it does not switch the tab. The `href` value is simply appended to the URL and the tabs don't switch.

Comment: look inspector at your browser will check that this loading jquery

Comment: I just did. jQuery is loading properly.

Comment: You can debugging your code and see if does everything expected?

if you do not have somewhere to go something wrong

Comment: I put in an alert to check if the code reaches the `simulate` part of it. The alert shows up but the tab does not switch.

Comment: try attaching a handle to the tab to which you want to go,

changes in Jquery selector $ ('a [rel = "tab2"]').trigger("click") for $('#tabid').trigger("click")

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Javascript and leverage the [tabs API](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/).

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="show_tab_2">Take me to Tab 2</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$("a.show_tap_2").click(function() {
  $('#mtabs_wrapper').tabs({
    active: 2
  });
});
```

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by JoseAPL's solution above. Thank you for the tabs API link. I'll definitely check it out sometime later!

Comment: I'm glad you've solved you're problem but mine is the correct answer. Simulating events isn't good practice when there's an easily accessible API to achieve the same effect.

If you used JQuery UI correctly you could replace all of your JS with just `$("tabs_wrapper").tabs()`.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to send a link with the hash in the url and it show the tab ?

Like - http://jsbin.com/mawevuwi/1#tab4

For that we would do something like this :

**CSS:**

```
.tabs > div { display:none; }
.tabs > div.active { display:block; }
```

Set up your **html** / ( use `<li>`'s if that's what you prefer )

```
<!-- links -->
<a href="#tab1">Tab1</a>
<a href="#tab2">Tab2</a>
<a href="#tab3">Tab3</a>
<a href="#tab4">Tab4</a>

<!-- content -->
<div class="tabs">
  <div id="tab1"> Tab one content </div>
  <div id="tab2"> Tab Two content </div>
  <div id="tab3"> 
       Tab Three content with a <a href="#tab1">link to tab 1</a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab4"> Tab Four content </div>
</div>
```

**with jQuery**

```
var $tabs = $('.tabs > div'), _currhash, $currTab;

function showTab() {
   if($currTab.length>0) {  
     $tabs.removeClass('active');
     $currTab.addClass('active');
   }
}
/* find the tabs and 'unlink' the id to prevent page jump */
$tabs.each(function() {
   var _id = $(this).attr('id');
   $(this).attr('id',_id+'_tab');
   /* eg we have given the tab an id of 'tab1_tab' */
});

/* set up an anchor 'watch' for the panels */
function anchorWatch() {
  if(document.location.hash.length>0) {
    /* only run if 'hash' has changed */
    if(_currhash!==document.location.hash) {
       _currhash = document.location.hash;
       /* we only want to match the 'unlinked' id's */
       $currTab = $(_currhash+'_tab');
       showTab();
   }
  }
} 
setInterval(anchorWatch,300);
```

---

- We  can have nice urls `/somepage#tab1`, can send these urls as links in email etc ..
- html is 'as designed' ( named anchors to content id's )
- Uses classes to do the /show/hide, so we can set CSS animations on the .active class if we like.

---

http://jsbin.com/dowemeve/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap's data-toggle = "tab" and in href use element #id, tab2 class should be tab-pane

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Take me to Tab 2</a>
<div class = "tab-content">
<div id="tab2" class = "tab-pane">
tab2 content goes here
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in tab header we have

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills m-1">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab"> tab1 </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a>
                            </li>
</ul>
```

and if you want another button to switch tabs like this:

```
 <div class="switch-tab btn" data-href="#tab_2">go tab 2</div>
```

and this is jquery event

```
$(document).on('click', '.switch-tab', function () {
                    var item=$(this);
                    $('li.nav-item a[href="'+item.data('href')+'"]').click();
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
if you have

```
<a id="goTab2" href="">Take me to Tab 2</a>
```

in jquery you can do this

```
$("#goTab2").click(function(){
$("#mtabs li:nth-child(2)").click();
return false;
 });
```

Comment: -1 The API has a function to show and hide tabs, duping events isn't good practice.

Comment: goood,but iam don't know this plugin so my answer not incorrect to -1 :)

Comment: Neither did I so I Googled it, not hard to do.